# Firebase SignInWIthEmailAndPasswod doesn't work

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm having issues implementing Login logic using Firebase email and password method. I've done everything according to documentation for 8 and 9 SDK versions but they don't work. To be more specific `.then` doesn't work.
I've implemented register and sign out without any issue, but login doesn't do anything. Here is login:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const loginUser = (email, password) => {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((userCredential) => {
            console.log('user', userCredential)
            history.push('/admin')
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            console.error(errorCode, errorMessage)
        });
    }
}

...
```

Whatever I try to log in `.then()` nothing happens, there is also no error. In network tab `verifyPassword` request is cancelled.

I really don't understand what is wrong there since it should be easy implementation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
firebase.auth()
```

is not available in Firebase V9. Make sure to read Docs of Firebase V9.
Because Firebase V9 doesn't built-in Object-Oriented Way. It was built with Functional
Way.

You can change as

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
       ////
}
initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const auth = getAuth()
const loginUser = (email, password) => {
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then((userCredential) => {
            console.log('user', userCredential)
            history.push('/admin')
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            console.error(errorCode, errorMessage)
        });
    }
}
```

Kindly read the Documentation to your doubts.
I would recommend you to watch Net Ninja's Firebase V9
Click [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zdvmgGsww0&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jERUGvbudErNCeSZHWUVlb)

Comment: Thanks for quick response. As I've mentioned, I've tried both implementations for 8 and 9 and none of them worked. That said I've succeded in running the rest of the code after successful login, I had to remove arrow function from '.then'.